# Conditional formatting to recognize a formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm hoping for conditional formatting to highlight cells that's got a formula in them and leave the ones that's just got plain text.

E.g.

`A          B           C           D
 1          1           3           0
 2          2           5 (=2+3)    3 (=4-1)
 3          3 (=1+2)    4           3
 4          8           4           2`

I've tried to use formulae to locate the `=` sign in order to pick out a "formula", however it does not work as such functions look at the content of the cell as a whole as opposed to going into the formula...

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the content of the workbook change? Or you just want to highlight formulas in a workbook you have received?

Comment: @pnuts Unfortunately I don't have that function...

Comment: @NiteshHalai No, the content won't change, I just need an indication of which ones are formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the cells in the worksheet (or whatever range you where you want the formulas to be highlighted). On the home tab, click on "find & Select", then select "formulas". This will select all cells with formulas.

After that, you can change the cell fill color of those selected cells so as to highlight them.